# Run clockwork only on one production instance (rails capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, clockwork

I have a production server with two instances app1 and app2 to which I use capistrano to deploy my application, ie: cap app1 deploy, cap app2 deploy.

I am now configuring the clockwork to schedule my delayed jobs. But what happens the jobs are scheduled twice, because the clockwork process runs  on both app1 and app2 after application is deployed.

How can I force the capistrano to run the clockwork process only on app2 ?

Thanks for a hint.
Miroslav

## SOLUTION

Add the following settings into the deploy.rb:

```
set :clockwork_role, :clock
```

And then configure only one of the instances to use the role :clock, ie:

```
server 'URL', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web clock}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can set some config variable to `true` in one case, and to `false` in the second, and check it when setting clockwork.

But want to mention that you are using different 'stages' (which are usually 'staging', 'production', 'qa', 'features', etc) for the different servers of one stage.
Capistrano has 'roles' (app, db, background jobs, etc) each can have several servers.

Also please mention which capistrano version you're using - there were big changes from 2 to 3

Comment: thanks for your comment faron. I have a load balancer on my production server and it points users either to app1 or to app2 based on the server capacity. app2 is more powerful than app1. Also I use capistrano v3.

Comment: @Miroslav does the suggested solution with boolean config variables work for you?

Comment: yes. I had to add set :clockwork_role, :clock into my deploy.rb file and then configure only one of the instances to use the role :clock. Thank you for guiding me there faron.